# calling a method inside a class-Python

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class Time:

    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.hour=x
        self.minute=y
        self.second=z

    def __str__(self):
        return "({:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d})".format(self.hour, self.minute, self.second)

    def time_to_int(time):
        minutes=time.hour*60+time.minute
        seconds=minutes*60+time.second
        return seconds

    def int_to_time(seconds):
        time=Time()
        minutes,time.second=divmod(seconds,60)
        time.hour,time.minute=divmod(minutes,60)
        return time

    def add_time(t1,t2):
        seconds=time_to_int(t1)+time_to_int(t2)
        return int_to_time(seconds)

start=Time(9,45,00)
running=Time(1,35,00)
done=add_time(start,running)
print(done)
```

I am new to python and i've been doing some practice lately.I came across a question and i've written the code for the same.But I am repeatedly getting an error: "add_time is not defined". I tried defining a main() method but then it doesn't print anything.Please help.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  Are `time_to_int` and so on supposed to be standalone functions, or methods of the class?  If the former, they need to be dedented outside the class definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't created an object to the above class.

Any function/method inside a class can only be accessed by an object of that class .For more information on the fundamentals of Object Oriented Programming, please check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) page.

Meanwhile for this to work, define your class in the following way :

```
class Time:

def __init__(self,x=None,y=None,z=None):
    self.hour=x
    self.minute=y
    self.second=z

def __str__(self):
    return "({:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d})".format(self.hour, self.minute, self.second)

def time_to_int(time):
    minutes=time.hour*60+time.minute
    seconds=minutes*60+time.second
    return seconds

def int_to_time(seconds):
    time=Time()
    minutes,time.second=divmod(seconds,60)
    time.hour,time.minute=divmod(minutes,60)
    return time

def add_time(t1,t2):
    seconds=time_to_int(t1)+time_to_int(t2)
    return int_to_time(seconds)
```

and outside the class block, write the following lines :

```
TimeObject = Time()
start=Time(9,45,00)
running=Time(1,35,00)
TimeObject.add_time(start,running)
print "done"
```

I however suggest you to write the add_time function outside the class because you are passing the objects to the class as the parameters to the function within the same class and it is considered as a bad design in object oriented programming. 
Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: one question.Now according to your code all the methods standalone?right?

Comment: No. start and running are objects of your class time. To access the add_time method of the class Time, you need another object and hence I have created a TimeObject just to access the add_time method. However I suggest you make the add_time method independant and rest can be within the class.

Comment: And here you've created a TimeObject but it has to be initialised,otherwise it would give an error.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, now I have edited so I can initialize it without having to pass it any parameter.

Comment: thanks @crazyglasses.I would have upvoted your ans but i've a reputation below 15.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of help! :)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight sure I will!

Comment: Haha. The @TheDarkKnight turns out of nowhere.

Comment: @crazyglasses i guess that's why he calls himself TheDarkKnight 

Answer (score 3):

**Hii Mathers25,**
I solve your problem try this below code to get the best output,

```
class TimeClass:

def __init__(self,x,y,z):
    self.hour = x
    self.minute = y
    self.second = z

def __str__(self):
    return "({:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d})".format(self.hour, self.minute, self.second)

def time_to_int(self,time):

    minutes = (time.hour * 60) + time.minute
    seconds = (minutes * 60) + time.second
    return seconds

def int_to_time(self,seconds):
    time = TimeClass(0,0,0)
        minutes,time.second=divmod(seconds,60)
        time.hour,time.minute=divmod(minutes,60)
        return time

def add_time(self,t1,t2):
    seconds = self.time_to_int(t1) + self.time_to_int(t2)
    # Call method int_to_time() using self keyword.
    return self.int_to_time(seconds)


# First time object create that time set value is 0 of hour,minute and second
TimeObject = TimeClass(0,0,0)

# After create second object
start=TimeClass(9,45,00)

# After create thired Object
running=TimeClass(1,35,00)

# Store the value which return by add_time() 
done = TimeObject.add_time(start,running)

# Display the value of done variable
print(done)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me as long as you specified 3 args in your constructor

```
def int_to_time(seconds):
    time=Time(0,0,0) # just set your 3 positionals args here
    minutes,time.second=divmod(seconds,60)
    time.hour,time.minute=divmod(minutes,60)
    return time
```

Another way to avoid it could be:

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0,z=0):
        self.hour=x
        self.minute=y
        self.second=z
```

If you want to add your functions to your class (such as `time_to_int`, `int_to_time` or even `add_time`) then you will need to indent with one more level of 4 spaces and add `self` to your method parameters

Comment: thanks! I got it know.I was trying to call a class method without using an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wage = 0
        self.hours_worked = 0

    def calculate_pay(self):
        return self.wage * self.hours_worked

alice = Employee()
alice.wage = 9.25
alice.hours_worked = 35
print('Alice:\n Net pay: {:.2f}'.format(alice.calculate_pay()))

barbara = Employee()
barbara.wage = 11.50
barbara.hours_worked = 20
print('Barbara:\n Net pay: {:.2f}'.format(barbara.calculate_pay()))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Works for me:

```
class C:
  def f(a, b):
    return a + b
  x = f(1,2)

print(C.x)
```

but you should not do such things. Code in class-level is executing when class is "creating", usually you want static methods or class methods (decorated with `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`) and execute code in some function/instantiated class. Also you can execute it on top (module) level if this is the simple script. Your snippet is "bad practice": class level (i'm talking about indentation) is for declarations, not for execution of something. On class-level is normal to execute code which is analogue of C macros: for example, to call decorator, to transform some method/attribute/etc - static things which are "pure" functions!